# How to access a ListBoxItem from a button created by the DataTemplate of this same ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, parent, datatemplate, visual-tree

## Problem

Given this piece of code, I want to have access to the properties (more specifically, its index) of the `ListBoxItem` that contains a `Button` when I press it. I've figured that I need to obtain the `Button`'s parent (which is an `StackPanel`) and then its `TemplatedParent` and then walk up the Visual Tree, but I don't know two very important things: how to do that efficiently to solve my problem, neither whether that really solves my problem.

### XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox"  Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="101"     Margin="237,312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!--src is the alias I gave to the xmlns that gives me access to the    assembly on which I'm working-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Items}">
             <DataTemplate.Resources>
                  <Style TargetType="Label">
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
                  </Style>
              </DataTemplate.Resources>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <!--Property1 to Property3 are defined in the Items type-->
                  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Property1}" Width="30"  MaxWidth="30"/>
                  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Property2}" Width="100" MaxWidth="100"/>
                  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Property3}" Width="250" MaxWidth="250"/>
                  <Button Content="X" Width="30" MaxWidth="30" Click="RemoveItemFromList"/>
              </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

### C Sharp

#### The piece of my code that works fine

```
//Somewhere in my code
ObservableCollection<Items> myStuff = createListOfItems();
myListBox.DataContext = myStuff;
myListBox.setBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

#### What I thought could be the answer (not working)

```
private void RemoveItemFromList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = (((sender as Button).Parent as StackPanel).TemplatedParent as ListBoxItem).IsSelected = true;
    myStuff.RemoveAt(myListBox.SelectedIndex); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemsControl` has a utility method you can use called `ContainerFromElement`.  You pass in an element from the visual subtree of an item container, and it gives you the container, e.g., the `ListBoxItem`:

```
var container = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(myListBox, sender as UIElement)
                as ListBoxItem;
```

Comment: I added a breakpoint after the line of code you are suggesting, the debugger shows that on run-time "container" is null. I even used a `MessageBox` to show the string representation of container afterwards and it threw an Exception.

Comment: Can you verify that the arguments being passed to `ContainerFromElement` are both non-null?  What happens if you pass `null` for the first parameter (in place of `myListBox`)?  Also, what happens if you remove the `as ListBoxItem` cast at the end?  Is the result of the method call non-null, and if so, what is its type?

Comment: My bad, I passed the first parameter wrong. Thanks! Really helpful, it worked!